# How to model grouping constraint in Knapsack problem?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, constraint-programming

I would like to add a new constraint to a standard Knapsack problem by introducing **groups**.
My variables are $x_c \in \mathbb{Z}^+,  c\in \mathbb{C}$. Where $\mathbb{C}$ is the set of all items. Each item belongs to a specific group $g_i, i\in \mathbb{G}$ and these groups are mutually exclusive.

I would like to optimize with limiting the number of groups my items belong to. (let's say $k$ groups)

Is it still possible to formulate this as a MIP problem and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i\in \mathbb{G}$, let binary variable $y_i$ indicate whether some item from group $i$ is selected.  Let $\overline{x}_c$ be an upper bound on $x_c$, which you can obtain from the knapsack constraint.  Impose the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
x_c &\le \overline{x}_c y_i &&\text{for $i\in \mathbb{G}$ and $c \in g_i$}\\
\sum_{i\in G} y_i &\le k
\end{align}
The first constraint enforces $x_c > 0 \implies y_i=1$.  The second constraint limits the number of selected groups to $k$.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed.